# What does "soft" in reinforcement learning literature mean?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have noticed that some papers refers to soft agents, and I thought that it was just an agent where the entropy is included in the objective function of the policy network. But now I'm not sure anymore.. Can anyone confirm or offer another explanation?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like this is the case. Asked about where the entropy enters SAC on [ai.stackexchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/where-does-entropy-enter-in-soft-actor-critic) and got a good answer for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

An epsilon-soft policy is a policy that takes every action with a probability of at least epsilon in every state. (Source http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/RLbook2018.pdf exercise 4.6 page 82 (104 of the pdf)). A soft policy is a policy that takes every action with positive probability (page 100/122).